# Is there any automated way to create hundreds of queues in weblogic?

Tags: weblogic12c

Am setting up a domain weblogic app server console for a project.

I have to create hundreds of JMS queues as part of it.

Is there any automated way to all these queues?

Comment: Correction : Is there any automated way to create all these queues?

Comment: Edit your question - don't put corrections in comments.

Answer (score 0):

WLST is your friend ! [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/jms_admin/wlst.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bash script and send a request using curl to your message queue.